# Scala sorting of case classes by type

Tags: scala, sorting, functional-programming, pattern-matching, case-class

Given some case classes which extend a common trait, I want to be able to define an Ordering (actually not necessarily, the goal is to sort them in that manner) dependent on their types. For example:

```scala
  sealed trait Element
  case class A(x: Int) extends Element
  case class B(x: Int) extends Element
  case class C(x: Int) extends Element
  case class D(x: Int) extends Element
  case class E(x: Int) extends Element
  case class F(x: Int) extends Element

  val elements: List[Element] = List(
    A(5), F(3), E(1), C(19), A(3), F(1)
  )
```

with an ordering of `F -> A -> all other cases`, such that the resulting list is `List(F(3), F(1), A(5), A(3), E(1), C(19))`. The ordering between elements of the same type does not matter.

I came up with multiple different solutions but they all seem convoluted, and I just feel like I'm missing some obvious way of accomplishing this. This is how I implemented it using an ordering:

```scala
  val sorted = elements.sorted{(a: Element, b: Element) => (a, b) match {
      case (_: F, _: F) =>  0
      case (_: F, _   ) => -1
      case (_   , _: F) =>  1
      case (_: A, _: A) =>  0
      case (_: A, _   ) => -1
      case (_   , _: A) =>  1
      case _            =>  0
    }
  }
```

However this would obviously scale horribly, and is not nice to look at..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just define an `implicit` `Ordering` for `Element` like this:

```
object Element {
  implicit val ord: Ordering[Element] = Ordering.by {
    case _: F => 0
    case _: A => 1
    case _ => 2
  }
}
```

Then `elements.sorted` will give you the answer you want.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of `Ordering.by` being a thing. That of course makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

How about introducing a class, that will hold the priority to sort the elements, for example:

```
class Prio(val prio: Int) {}
case class A() extends Prio(5)
case class B() extends Prio(3)
case class C() extends Prio(9)
case class D() extends Prio(7)

object Prio {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    List(A(), B(), C(), D())
      .sortBy(_.prio)
      .foreach(println)
  }
}
```

This gives the following result:

```
B()
A()
D()
C()
```

You can of course mix in other interfaces, add values to the type classes. The `Prio` class can be even enriched in more priorities that can be used in different situations.

Since you only want to have `A` as first and `F` as last, you can use the following ordering:

```
class Prio(val prio: Int) {}
case class A() extends Prio(-1)
case class B() extends Prio(0)
case class C() extends Prio(0)
case class D() extends Prio(0)
case class E() extends Prio(0)
case class F() extends Prio(1)
```

Comment: That's a very good idea! It even seems like quite an obvious choice, simply providing a field which can implicitly be used for sorting.. Thanks!